# How can I copy resource files from my Visual Studio VB NET application onto the local system when it's executed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll, copy, resources

I want to be able to copy resources I've compiled into the program to a location on the local machine where the application is run. Mostly a few DLLs that my program will not use, but others will (think Installer type of application).. But I can't find a way to reference the resources by path in order to do a File.Copy, for instance:

```
File.Copy(My.Resources.conversion, BinPath & "conversion.dll")
```

...tells me *"Value of type 'Byte()' cannot be converted to 'String'"*. And I get why, obviously the first parameter needs to be a string path and not the resource itself. Is there a better way to copy resources or how can I obtain a reference path to the resource so I can use `File.Copy`?

For what it's worth, I've also tried

```
File.WriteAllBytes(BinPath & "conversion.dll", My.Resources.conversion)
```

...which "works" to copy it where I want it, but then I get errors when I try to call regsvr32 on the
new dll: "*The module ... was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found."*

If there's a better way altogether, I'm open to any idea.

Comment: *"I've also tried File.WriteAllBytes(BinPath & "conversion.dll", My.Resources.conversion) ...which "works" to copy it where I want it"*. In that case, you're asking a question that you already have an answer to. Get rid of all the irrelevant information and ask the question you actually need an answer to.

Comment: So, does your DLL have a RegegisterService?

Comment: Check if my answer helps you handle this issue and if it helps, please [consider accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If not, please feel free to let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps work for me:

1. Change the 'Build Action' of the dll in 'Resources' file to 'Embedded Resource'.
   [image]
2. Use the following method to save resource file to disk.

   ```
   Public Sub WriteResourceToFile(ByVal resourceName As String, ByVal fileName As String)
       Using resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)
           Using file = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
               resource.CopyTo(file)
           End Using
       End Using
   End Sub
   ```

Example of usage:

```
WriteResourceToFile("yournameSpace.conversion.dll", BinPath & "conversion.dll")
```